# Retrieve row data on checkbox selection in Ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid

I want to retrieve the row data on checkbox selection. Currently in ag-grid, on selecting a row we can retrieve the row data. Or we can do a multi row select, so rows details can be retrieved. So is there any way to retrieve the row data on checkbox selection. Or multiple rows data on checkboxes selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use Row Selection
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-selection/?framework=javascript#gsc.tab=0
You may use this **onSelectionChanged: onSelectionChanged** property or
**onRowSelected: rowSelectedFunc**

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion helped me to resolve the issue.